# Can we use TFS Comparision API in .NET Windows Forms/ WPF Application

Tags: wpf, xml, winforms, tfs, comparison

I would like to compare two XML text and show color coded comparison as done in TFS or Beyond Compare in .net Windows Forms or WPF application.

Just looking for a way to do it using some already defined API in .net or TFS API .

Answer (score 6):

The Team Foundation Server merge tool is a simple executable (`diffmerge.exe`) that is shipped when you install TFS client part. Is it not part of the TFS API.

What you could do is launch an open source command line tool to do the job, such as [WinMerge](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html).

I wouldn't use diffmerge.exe for two reasons:

- it's probably not possible to use it in a personal/commercial project as it's shipped and licensed with TFS
- it's a **crappy tool**, probably the *worst chunk of bits of TFS*

Comment: Team Explorer simply has the ability to launch an exe with a customisable command line. The command lines to use for various tools are documented for many Windows diff/merge tools (eg. Source Gear Diff Merge in its documentation file here: http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/ )

Comment: @Richard Yes, it's only able to start a process with command line parameters. [Here's a useful link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) that helps using other diff/merge tools instead of the built-in and crappy "diffmerge.exe" tool.